# What is the earliest documented use of behavior trees?

Tags: ai, tree, behavior, behavior-tree

I'm curious about when [behavior trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_tree_(artificial_intelligence,_robotics_and_control)) first appeared in the context of AI design. I've looked at many sources (e.g., GDC talks, academic literature such as [*Behavior Trees in Robotics and AI: An Introduction*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.00084) and [*A Survey of Behavior Trees in Robotics and AI*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341341939_A_Survey_of_Behavior_Trees_in_Robotics_and_AI), and various online articles and tutorials) and most of them state that behavior trees were first used for game AI (although a few sources, such as [the wiki for the gdxAI library](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki/Behavior-Trees), say that they were used in robotics first) and give examples of prominent games (Halo 2 is frequently mentioned) that used them. However, this assertion is usually made with little supporting evidence.

Assuming that behavior trees did indeed originate in the context of game development (not robotics), in what game were they first used?

There's evidence that the 1996 game [SimCopter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimCopter) used behavior trees in some form: former Maxis employee [Don Hopkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Hopkins) has said that it used a visual behavior tree programming language called "SimAntics" ([link](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15003155)) and one of the game files, `people.df`, contains several plaintext comments that refer to "reaction trees", such as:

> can't call rxn trees from non-reaction trees, or will be stuck in reaction--can't be interrupted while in reaction loop can however call them from other reaction trees--won't be interrupted, though

Unfortunately `people.df` is a binary file and (as far as I know) its format hasn't been reverse-engineered, so it's hard to know if the reaction trees it contains are sufficiently powerful to be considered "true" behavior trees.

Are there any earlier games with documented use of behavior trees or similar constructs that would now be considered behavior trees?

Comment: This looks more like a question about the history of computer science, rather than a question about how to develop a game today. This site specializes in the latter, so we might not attract the expertise you need to answer this question to your satisfaction.

Comment: You're right, it's not a practical question (although it's possible that knowing more about the origins of behavior trees - for example, the original set of nodes - could yield new insights regarding their use in a modern context). I'd welcome any suggestions regarding better places to post this question; none of the history-related [SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) seemed like a good fit and Google produced irrelevant results when I tried to find forums related to game development history (which probably says more about the current state of Google than the existence of such sites).